# jquery navigation menu div dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a div to drop down when you click two of the navigation links (Link 1 and Links 3 only). So far I can only make it drop by clicking on the navigation block ('.navBox'). how can I pass the  href... links instead?
Please help..

HTML/jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navBox').toggle(function(){
        $('.lowerContainer').slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $('.lowerContainer').slideUp();
    });
});

<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logoBox">
                Logo
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lowerContainer" style="display: none;">
    <div class="lowerWrapper">
        <div id="boxed">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="contentArea">
        <div class="sportsIcons">
            <div id="boxed">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="line">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way: give those link a class and select them.

A way to that works with your current DOM structure:

```
$('div.navBox a').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML == "Link 1" &&
           this.innerHTML == "Link 3";
}).whatYouWant();
```

Comment: What do you mean by innerHTML?

Comment: @OliOlivier. It's what inside of `<a> ... </a>` this case it's `...`

Comment: is that: <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li> Or just  href="#">Link 1

Answer (score 0):

Use $('.navBox ul li a') or give the links a class name, and use that.

Comment: This seems to work but on all links instead of specific links (link 1 and Link 2) anyway I pass the those two specific links?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a:contains("Link 1"), a:contains("Link 3")', '.navBox').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.lowerContainer').slideToggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reorder your markup so you have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">menu item</a>
        <div>Dropdown</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">menu item</a>
        <div>Dropdown</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That way you could solve for it doing:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```